# Dropzone + Active Storage event listener in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, addeventlistener, dropzone.js, dom-events, rails-activestorage

I am using dropzone with and active storage to upload files directly upload files to the s3 server from the client side. Currently I am getting file from dropzone with `addedfile` event of dropzone and uploading it via `new ActiveStorage.DirectUpload(file, url);`. Now according to the documentation they have provided some event listeners which I can use to show progress of upload to the user but they are only working if I am using a normal form and a submit button. It does not work if I upload files via Javascript.
Here is my code:

```
dropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
    const upload = new ActiveStorage.DirectUpload(file, url);
    upload.create((error, blob) => {
        if(error) return;
        alert('file uploaded');
    }
}


addEventListener("direct-upload:start", event => {
    console.log('This does not work');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`DirectUpload` doesn't dispatch events.

`DirectUploadController` does, and it uses `DirectUpload` to do the actual upload, like you are doing in your example code.  You don't need to listen for events from `DirectUploadController` since you can infer when the event would be dispatched.

To do something where you would expect the `direct-upload:start` and `direct-upload:end` events, change your code to something like:

```
dropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
    const upload = new ActiveStorage.DirectUpload(file, url);

    console.log("direct-upload:start") 

    upload.create((error, blob) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log("direct-upload:error") 
            return;
        }
    }

    console.log("direct-upload:end")
}
```